# How to transform keras model to tpu model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am trying to transform my Keras model in the Google cloud console into a TPU model. Unfortunatelly I am getting an error as shown below. My minimal example is the following:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import tensorflow as tf
import os
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
         tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

My output is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "cloud_python4.py", line 11, in <module>
     tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.tpu' has no attribute 'keras_to_tpu_model'
```

The keras_to_tpu_model method seems experimental as indicated on the tensorflow website. Has it recently been removed? If so, how can I proceed to make use of TPUs to estimate my Keras model? If the keras_to_tpu_model method would be still available, why can I not invoke it?

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you defined you TPU_WORKER as below

```py
import os
TPU_WORKER = ‘grpc://’ + os.environ[‘COLAB_TPU_ADDR’]
```

Instead of converting your model to TPU, build a distribution strategy. This is the method by which the batch will be distributed to the eight TPUs and how the loss from each will be calculated.

```py
resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)
tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

With the strategy build and compile your model. This should work quite nicely for regression.

```py
with strategy.scope():
  model = Sequential() 
  model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))
  model.add(Dense(32))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
```

Answer (score 2):

Import keras from tensorflow. 
This is because `tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model( )`' requires a **tensorflow** version Model, not the keras version.

For example, use `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation` instead. And so on.

Comment: did not quite work. I did actually replace the keras model by the tensorflow.keras version as you suggested. But I still get the error message "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.tpu' has no attribute 'keras_to_tpu_model''. It says that attribute is experimental in the tensorflow reference. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to update to the latest tensorflow version? If you are using pip you can do `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`